# is it possible to store sessions with google cloud storage or s3?

Tags: session, amazon-s3, filenames, scalability, google-cloud-storage

I was searching for a cheap and a good scalable way to store sessions within my app !

so could I store the sessions token and other parameter in one line, then create empty file which his name is that token !

then i can store the file either in s3 or google cloud storage !

when I check if a session is valid I just check if that file exist !

Comment: Or even better - store the session encoded as a unique Datastore key, and then just do a get by key to check if the session is valid.

Comment: What kind of app? Desktop? Web? There may be security concerns with desktop apps having read/write access to a bucket containing sessions for all instances of your app.

Comment: @rein, thank you for your response, could you clarify more ?